# Rails 4 SyntaxError: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails and feel like I'm missing something. Working with Rails 4.2.10 trying to invoke jQuery commands but keep getting the same error:

```
irb(main):001:0> $(document).ready()
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        6: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
SyntaxError ((irb):1: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name)
```

or inside a controller with the same error...

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    $(document).ready();
    @products = Product.all
  end
...
```

I'm using this in my Gemfile, `gem 'jquery-rails'`, note I ran `bundle install` already

and, my `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` looks like this,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to run javascript code (`$(document).ready()`) in the Rails console (irb). You, naturally, can't do that. Try, instead, using the developer console in your browser.

Comment: @jvillian is it possible to run jquery commands inside a Rails controller?

Comment: The controller is Ruby code, jQuery is JavaScript. JavaScript runs on the client, not the server.

Comment: Why would you want to run jquery commands inside a Rails controller? That's doesn't really make sense. (See @Barmar comment).

Comment: A key thing to note - the rails controller talks to the server, not the client, so it would never know if the client is 'ready'. Here's a good article that will help clarify things: https://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/

Comment: @gwalshington - Picking at nits here. I think it would be more precise to say that the Rails controller is ruby code that is executed on (or perhaps, by) the server. Or, possibly "ruby code that runs on the server". But, I think it's somewhat imprecise (and possibly confusing) to say that a rails controller "talks to the server".

Comment: @jvillian Sure - what I'm getting at is that the server will do it's thing first, then send anything needed to the client, THEN any client-side code will run. Therefore, document.ready will execute by the client, after that particular `home` controller method is finished. Additionally, that controller doesn't really even know what `document` is, because it could really be any number of clients. I feel like this is something that RoR newbs don't get at first, because you are able to use ruby on both server and client, so one assumes all languages can be used by both client and server.

Comment: @gwalshington - In what instances is ruby code used on the client?

Comment: @jvillian  embedded ruby in html.

Comment: @gwalshington - embedded ruby in html is run on the server, not the client. So, I guess you are correct, it is confusing.

Comment: lol exactly :) I should have said `able to use ruby on both server and client FILES`. so I'm guessing this guy, who has prob stopped reading this, was assuming JQuery can be used anywhere, even though his example didn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @gwalshington that article explains a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby global variables are written using the dollar sign.

```
$foo = 'global'
```

Would be a valid global variable.  So when you try to use that jquery line it thinks you are trying to set a global variable because of code, inside the `.rb` file, is getting run as Ruby code.  So, as the commenters have said, you need to move that javascript code so that it runs in the view and thus gets evaluated as javascript code, not Ruby code.